# Is there an easier Whistle Sprint Alternative to execute?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

[Whistle Sprinting](https://www.zeldaspeedruns.com/botw/techniques/whistle-sprint) is a glitch in Breath of the Wild where you hold the whistle button and tap the B button to continuously sprint without draining stamina.

In Tears of the Kingdom, this glitch has been patched. However, the community has found alternative whistle sprinting techniques. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFjjaEvo358&t=540) shows one Whistle Sprint alternative called the Bow Sprint. You alternate between pressing the B button and the Right Trigger. I have been able to do this glitch but not consistently.

I was wondering if there is another alternative Whistle Sprint that is easier to execute than the Bow Sprint?

Comment: Based on [this video](https://youtu.be/DFjjaEvo358?t=460), there are alternatives, but none of them look significantly easier than bow sprinting to my eye.

Comment: This may not always work, but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrylnQtqIA4) shows a glitch that allows you to get easily farmable 30-minute speed up level three seared steaks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. Possibly in the future better methods will be discovered, but currently there aren't any.